# Issue with keydown in jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, keydown

Please help. I am having some difficulty getting data to post to the database with jquery keydown

1. With the if ( e.which == 13 ) { added to the script no data enters the database, but I receive a complete affirmative message from Ajax section
2. If i remove the e.which ==13 section it works but adds each letter i type on a seperate row in the database
   What exactly am I doing wrong?  I am using cakephp if that makes a difference

-

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#notify').bind("keydown", function(e){
        if ( e.which == 13 ) {

            var notes  = $('.note').val();  

            var targeturl = 'http://www.domain.com/notifications/index/33/'+notes;  
            //alert(targeturl);

            $.ajax({    
                dataType: "html",
                type: "POST",
                evalScripts: true,              
                url: targeturl,     
                complete: function () {
                    // Handle the complete event
                    var result = "Thanks for update your fans";
                    $("#thanksfornotes").fadeOut("slow").html(result);
                }     
            })

        }

    });
});
```

Comment: You should really prefer to us `.on()` instead of `.bind()`. 

What is the result of `console.log(e.which)` and what is the result of `console.log(e.keyCode)`?

Comment: What's running on the backend to enter data into the Database, a PHP page? Why append `notes` to the URL...it could have spaces, right? Why not just send it as a parameter in the ajax (not in the URL) and read it out of the params on the backend?

Comment: Herbertp the .on worked thanks

Comment: Chase, your suggestion seems to be the best way to do this. Could you illustrate how this can be done, thanks